# PHP If URL Statement

Tags: php

I need to do some basic if URL statement stuff but I know *nothing* about PHP. I've tried a few examples I've found online but they don't seem to work.

Note: this is for a wordpress blog if that makes a different.

I want a "PHP IF URL" statement to do the following:

If URL referrer = twitter.com then echo

```
"Follow us on <a href="twitter.com/example">Twitter</a>
```

If URL referrer = facebook.com then echo

```
"Follow us on <a href="facebook.com/example">Facebook</a>
```

If no url referrer or none of the above echo "Follow us on Nothing"

Comment: Please share the few examples you've tried, and you could learn where it went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can check your referrer by accessing [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). You can parse out the url using [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) if necessary.

Read carefully the warning on php.net regarding the referrer:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. **In short, it cannot really be trusted**.

Comment: Asker should also note that when coming from `https` sites, the HTTP referrer is not set.  Facebook and Twitter use `https` AFIK.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve url from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], parse it with parse_url and then echo your response based on what is in the response from parse_url. It returns an associative array where the host key is the hostname.

```
<?php
if ( empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) )
    echo 'Follow us on Nothing';
else {
    $ref = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );

    switch( $ref['host'] ) {
    case 'twitter.com':
        echo 'Follow us on <a href="http://twitter.com/example">Twitter</a>';
        break;
    case 'facebook.com':
        echo 'Follow us on <a href="http://facebook.com/example">Facebook</a>';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Follow us on Nothing';
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Remember to check if there is anything at all in the referrer. Not all browsers send it and it will not be sent if the user was not sent here from another site, ex: the url was manually typed in.

Also note that if the user navigated from a page using https there wont be sent any reference either.

Answer (score 0):

The output will be stored in $str.

```
$url = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
$url_parts = parse_url($url);

switch($url_parts["host"])
{
  case "twitter.com":
    $str = "Follow us on <a href=\"twitter.com/example\">Twitter</a>";
    break;
  case "facebook.com":
    $str = "Follow us on <a href=\"facebook.com/example\">Facebook</a>";
    break;
  default:
    $str = "";
    break;
}
```